# Ensure uniqueness in an array after index 0

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given this code:

```
random: function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
}

let result = []

result.push(random()) // it doesn't matter if this integer is pushed again in the next line
[...Array(10)].forEach((_, i) => result.push(random())) // all of these have to be unique
```

How can I make sure that no duplicates are pushed to `result` *except* possibly the first *while* maintaining the length of the array at 11?

Comment: Use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - check that it is -1 before pushing.

Comment: Why except the first? That would never be a dupe

Comment: Your array could theoretically contain only 2 elements, right?

Comment: @goodvibration It should have 11 according to this code.

Comment: Well, your definition does not imply this fact.

Comment: You would have to loop until you had 10 unique numbers. Now you only loop 10 times

Comment: So in a nutshell: how to generate 10 unique random numbers and then one more which we don't care about…?

Comment: Given the numbers are in the range 1 to 100, you can start with an array of 1 to 100 and randomly *splice* 10 values from it.

Comment: shuffle and slice and evrything nice ;)

Comment: Take `arr = [1,2,...,100]` and use `Math.random()` in order to shuffle it. Then use `arr.slice(0,10)` and add a random value between 1 and 100 at the beginning of it.

Comment: Why do you need to maintain the length of the array (within the array itself) when the language already does that for you?